# Wifi does not work on Dell Inspiron N5520

Tags: 12.04, wireless, inspiron

Купил сегодня ноут Dell Inspiron N5520 на нем стояла ubuntu 11.10 я решил поставить по свежее версию 12.10 но перестал работать wi-fi

Translation:

Today I bought a new Dell Inspiron N5520 laptop, but it had 11.10 on it. I decided to update to version 12.10, but the wi-fi stopped working.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to translate your question into english so as to help other people understand and find an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry. I can understand some Russian, but not answer in Russian.

Make sure that wi-fi is activated both on the keyboard, if it has a way of deactivating it, and in the network menu in Ubuntu.

If it still does not work, another option is to install 'Wicd network manager' on the computer. It might work better.

To give you better help, it would be necessary to look into system logs to find out why it is not working. I hope that Wicd can help you.

Comment: Since you can understand Russian, can you translate the post and suggest an edit?

Comment: Of course. There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in similar situation: Using LiveCD install "Additional Drivers" Applet, then use that and connected over wire(Ethernet) to internet installed the driver it suggested me for my Broadcom wifi card. Hope it helps you.